# Calculate $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\int_t^TB_\tau dB_\tau}\right]$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, moment-generating-functions

I just learned basic stochastic calculus and found it extremely hard to calculate $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\int_t^TB_\tau dB_\tau}\right]$, where $B_\tau$ is a standard Brownian motion.

I can do the calculation that $\int_t^TB_\tau dB_\tau=\frac{1}{2}(B_T^2-B_t^2)-\frac{1}{2}(T-t)$, but I don't know how to continue. I have tried Ito's lemma, but it seemed to make the calculation harder; I also tried Feynman-Kac Formula, but I cannot find any proper function form to solve the PDE...

Appreciate any help/hint!

Comment: $B_t$ has a normal distribution so the distribution of $B_t^2$ is chi square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing $$B_T = (B_T-B_t)+B_t$$ we find that

$$\int_t^T B_s \, dB_s = \frac{1}{2} (B_T-B_t)^2+  (B_T-B_t)B_t - \frac{1}{2} (T-t).$$
By the independence of the increments of Brownian motion, we know that $B_t$ and $B_T-B_t$ are independent, and it follows that

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}\exp\left( \int_t^T B_s \, dB_s \right) &= \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2}(T-t) \right) \mathbb{E}f(B_t) \tag{1} \end{align*}

where

$$f(x) := \mathbb{E}\exp \left( \frac{1}{2} (B_T-B_t)^2 + (B_T-B_t) x \right).$$

Using the scaling property,  $B_T-B_t \sim B_{T-t} \sim \sqrt{T-t} B_1$, we see that

$$f(x) = \mathbb{E}\exp \left( \frac{T-t}{2} B_1^2 + \sqrt{T-t} B_ 1 x \right).$$

To compute this function, we need to do some computations involving the Gaussian density. As $B_1 \sim N(0,1)$, we have

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left( \frac{T-t}{2} y^2 + \sqrt{T-t} yx \right) \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2} y^2 \right) \, dy.$$ In particular, we see that the integral on the right-hand side is infinite if $T-t \geq 1$, and therefore we will assume from now on that $T-t<1$. If we set $\sigma^2 := 1/(1+t-T)$, then

\begin{align*} f(x) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2} \frac{y^2}{\sigma^2} + yx \sqrt{T-t} \right) \, dy \\ &= \sqrt{\sigma^2} \exp \left( \frac{1}{2} x^2 \sigma^2 (T-t) \right) \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} (y- x \sqrt{T-t} \sigma^2)^2 \right) \, dy}_{=1} \\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t-T}} \exp \left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{T-t}{1+t-T} x^2 \right). \end{align*}

Plugging this into $(1)$, we obtain that

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}\exp \left( \int_t^T B_s \, dB_s \right) &= \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} (T-t) \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t-T}} \mathbb{E}\exp \left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{T-t}{1+t-T} B_t^2 \right)  \\ &= \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} (T-t) \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t-T}} \mathbb{E}\exp \left( \frac{t}{2} \frac{T-t}{1+t-T} B_1^2 \right). \end{align*}

As $\mathbb{E}e^{rB_1^2} = 1/\sqrt{1-2r}$ for any $r<1$ (you can check this using the density of $B_1$), we conclude that

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}\exp \left( \int_t^T B_s \, dB_s \right)&= \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} (T-t) \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t-T}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- t \frac{T-t}{1+t-T}}} \\ &= \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} (T-t) \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t-T-(T-t) t}}. \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much! I wonder if I can use the scaling property to write $B_t \sim \sqrt{t}B_1$ and replace everything by $B_1$, then the calculation involing Gaussian density is proceeded with $B_1$. I solved a slightly different result... Is there something wrong with this method?

Comment: One possible explanation I think is that if I write $B_T-B_t\sim\sqrt{T-t}B_1,\ B_t\sim\sqrt{t}B_1$, then it is a mistake because $B_T-B_t$ and $B_t$ are independent. Therefore I have to use different "notation" (i.e., $x$ and $y$ in your answer) to separately denote these two random variables. Is it reasonable?

Comment: @Huaixin Yes, first you need to use independence of $B_T-B_t$ and $B_t$ and then you can use the scaling property. You can't do it the other way round because, as you say yourself, $\sqrt{T-t} B_1$ and $\sqrt{t}B_1$ are not independent.

Comment: Got it, thanks again!